# Testing set membership in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused as to why the following method to test set membership is not working in my program. If I run the following program with any text file as the argument, in the output I only see "Second". I thought both if statements should be testing the same thing.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class Exc0 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            File input = new File(args[0]);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            int[] delimiters = {' ', '(', ',', ')'};

            int current;
            while ((current = reader.read()) != -1){
                if ((Arrays.asList(delimiters).contains(current))){
                    System.out.println("First");
                }
                if (current == ' ' || current == '(' || current == ',' || current == ')'){
                    System.out.println("Second");
                }
            }


        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you call `Arrays.asList(delimiters)` you get a list with a single instance of `int[]`, not with four instances of `int`/`Integer`.

In general, for checking membership in sets of characters you may be better of with a `String`:

```
String delimiters = "() ,";
if (delimiters.indexOf(current) >= 0) {
    System.out.println("First");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Corrected based on other answer)*

Since there is no `List<int>`, `Arrays.asList(int[] something)` can not return what you are hoping for. While, at first I thought, it would instead return a `List<Integer>`, this is not the case. As dasblinkenlight pointed out, it will actually return a `List<int[]>` with one element instead. (Therefore, declaring `current` as an `Integer` instead of an `int` will not fix the bug, but declaring `delimiters` as an `Integer[]` probably will as suggested by Marc Baumbach in the comments.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing that based on your suggestion. It did not change the output

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<int[]>` when passing in an `int[]`. The fix will likely require that you declare your original delimiters to be an `Integer[]`. Something like: `Integer[] delimiters = {Integer.valueOf(' '), Integer.valueOf('('), Integer.valueOf(','), Integer.valueOf(')')};`

Comment: Yep... Correct... That's what you get for answering without actually trying the code... dasblinkenlight posted the right answer above...

Comment: You had the right approach to fixing the current code and pointed out the initial problem. I had to double check it in code myself to see if that would fix it. :)